# how to handle a large php mysql $_POST UPDATE/INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something like this so I don't have to type out all of my post entries. I can't seems to get this to work though.

edit: added some changes.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
    $key = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'";  
    $value = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
    $qstring = "UPDATE load_test SET ".$key."=".$value." WHERE Id = '".$_POST['id']."'";  
        mysql_query($qstring);
}
```

Comment: boy, you're indeed in trouble with accepted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        @$select.=" `".mysql_real_escape_string($k)."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($v)."',";
}
$select = rtrim($select,',');
$select = "UPDATE load_test SET".$select." WHERE id=".$_POST['id'];
mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());;
```

try this is alot faster then the previous one you want need to do more then 1 query
and other then that i think it's safe enough to escape the key since trying updating a column that doesn't exist doesn't get you anywhere, and trying to make an injection escaping will protect you from that, you should though make sure the id is numeric

Comment: do I also have to do something like $key = $value on the UPDATE i just noticed that. it won't know where to place the $value in the table

Comment: yeah probably if the key is the same thing as the column name

Comment: Need to wrap $key in backticks, after removing any backticks from the $key itself.  It's still crazy insecure, as the user can update any field in that table that they like, just by posting any $key name they like.

Comment: You also need to escape the $_POST['id'].

Comment: Seconding that this extremely insecure. El Yobo's idea of whitelisting the fields that are allowed to be updated is spot on.

Comment: I just tried running the code and its not updating. no error being returned either. but when i do the query like this `$qstring="UPDATE load_test SET word = '".$_POST['word']."', type = '".$_POST['type']."'
     WHERE Id = '".$_POST['id']."'";` it works fine

Comment: only weakness it might have is not checking if the posted id is numeric or not(and that i've already mentioned), since any injections on the key or value part will be escaped and therefor handled as a name alt. string for the table which will as a result only output an error if you try to inject the key with anything since it will try to find an column that's not there

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do here is incredibly, dangerously insecure.

```
// List the fields that may be updated here
$expectedFields = array('fielda', 'fieldb');

// Updated values to be stored here
$updates = array();

// Generate the update strings
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $expectedFields)) {
        $updates[] = "`$key` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."'";
    }
}  

// Do all updates at once
$qstring = "UPDATE load_test SET " . join(', ', $updates) . " WHERE Id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "'";  
mysql_query($qstring);
```

This improves several things

- All updates happen in one query, rather than one per field
- The fields are validated (and sanitised, as they're only accepted if they're in the valid list)
- The ID value is also sanitised

Comment: is there a secure way to do it? Or a better method of typing out all the required field names and post. sometimes I have to update like 20 fields and making sure the post value and field name are in the right spot for the update can being confusing.

Comment: @Breezer - it will generate UPDATE load_test SET `somefield` = 'some value' WHERE Id = 'some key', the same as you have now updated yours to do.  So if that was your downvote, read the answer again, think about it, and correct your vote.

Comment: @acctman: a) you should use PDO or mysqli b) you need to escape the $_POST['id'] value as well c) you need to escape the $key as well d) you need to check that $key is a valid field name that you want to update.

Comment: you're running the query after the loop therefor only updating the last set of the loop that's what're wrong

Comment: Ahaha, ok, you're right there; copied and pasted his original.  I'll edit to provide a somewhat more secure all round solution anyway.

Comment: I think the $expectedFields is wrong... i put the field names in there, and when I upload the values set where the field named from $expectedFields... should it be something like this $updates[] = "`$key` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";

Comment: What did you put in the expectedFields?  It should just be an array of the names of the fields that you want to let be updated.